# How to count three consecutive records with same values in a column based on the value of another column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table attendance as follows:

```
create table attendance (id int, name varchar(30), status varchar(10), date date)
```

This table has the following records:

```
insert into attendance values (1,'John','absent','2016-03-01');
insert into attendance values (1,'John','absent','2016-03-02');
insert into attendance values (1,'John','absent','2016-03-03');
insert into attendance values (2,'Sam','present','2016-03-04');
insert into attendance values (3,'Sam','absent','2016-03-05');
insert into attendance values (1,'John','absent','2016-03-06');
insert into attendance values (1,'John','absent','2016-03-07');
insert into attendance values (1,'John','absent','2016-03-08');
insert into attendance values (1,'John','present','2016-03-09');
insert into attendance values (1,'John','absent','2016-03-10');
insert into attendance values (1,'John','absent','2016-03-11');
insert into attendance values (1,'John','present','2016-03-12'); 
insert into attendance values (1,'John','absent','2016-03-13');
```

Now I want to count that how many times a person has three consecutive absent records.
The result should be as follows:

```
id name count
 1  John   2
```

because John is absent for three consecutive days two times.

If they have 6 absents on 6 consecutive dates, then it should count 2 i.e (3+3).

It should count 1 for 3 consecutive absents on 3 consecutive dates i.e if John is absent for 1,2 and 3 march, it should count 1. but if John is absent for 1,2 and 4 march then it should not count 1.
4 or 5 absents should be counted as 1.

If there is no entry for a date, It is considered 'Present'.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution. Recursive part creates groups of rows of status "absent". 
The solution uses [recursive CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html) and [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html).

```
WITH RECURSIVE a(id, name, date, n)  as (
    SELECT id, name, q.date, 1 as n
    FROM (
        SELECT id, name, date,
            date-lag(date) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date) as lag
        FROM  attendance
        WHERE status='absent'
    ) q
    WHERE lag >1 or lag is null
    UNION
    SELECT a.id, a.name, a.date, a.n + 1
    FROM a
    JOIN attendance at ON (
           a.id = at.id and at.name = a.name and at.date = a.date + n)
    WHERE at.status='absent'
)
SELECT id, name, sum(long_absences) FROM (
    SELECT id, name, count(*)/3 as long_absences
    FROM a
    GROUP BY id, name, date having count(*) >=3
    ) as absences
GROUP BY id, name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I beleive @user103153 solution is better so I'll just add this as an example of another technique. I did not have PostgreSQL to try with so some adjustments likely have to be made. I also use a calendar table, in psql either a recursive CTE or a generating expression can be used:

We start by constructing the domain of names and dates:

```
select distinct d, name 
from calendar c 
cross join attendance a
```

from there we can construct the status:

```
select nc.name, nc.d, a.date, a.name as aname
         , coalesce(a.status, 'present') as status        
from ( 
    select distinct d, name 
    from calendar c 
    cross join attendance a
) as nc
left join attendance a                                                       
    on a.name = nc.name
    and a.date = nc.d
```

Then by using a common trick we can construct groups of consecutive name, date and status:

```
select name, d, status, row_number() over (partition by name order by d) 
                      - row_number() over (partition by name, status order by d) as grp 
from (
    select nc.name, nc.d, a.date, a.name as aname
         , coalesce(a.status, 'present') as status        
    from ( 
        select distinct d, name 
        from calendar c cross join attendance a
    ) as nc
    left join attendance a                                                       
        on a.name = nc.name
        and a.date = nc.d
)
```

Next step is to determine the start and stop for each interval where status is 'absent':

```
select name, min(d), max(d) from (
    select name, d, status, row_number() over (partition by name order by d) 
                          - row_number() over (partition by name, status order by d) as grp 
    from (
        select nc.name, nc.d, a.date, a.name as aname
             , coalesce(a.status, 'present') as status        
        from ( 
            select distinct d, name 
            from calendar c 
            cross join attendance a
        ) as nc
        left join attendance a                                                       
            on a.name = nc.name
            and a.date = nc.d
    ) 
) 
where status = 'absent' 
group by grp, name order by min(d);

NAME                           2          3         
------------------------------ ---------- ----------
John                           03/01/2016 03/03/2016
Sam                            03/05/2016 03/05/2016
John                           03/06/2016 03/08/2016
John                           03/10/2016 03/11/2016
John                           03/13/2016 03/13/2016
```

Finally (left as an exercise :-) we take the length of the interval and integer divide that with 3 and filter out the ones with 0. Then it's just a matter of summing the number per name.

Answer (score 0):

I think I cobbled together something that does what you're looking for. I used several subqueries to check for consecutive absences, and also to avoid double dipping on a long absence (meaning 6 days in a row should count ONLY the 2 combined marks from the first day, and not the individual marks on absences 2-4, 3-5, and 4-6).

Would be curious to see if there's a more elegant solution from someone else.

```
    select 
            z.name, 
            sum(z.absent_marks) 
    from (
            select 
                    sub1.* 
            from (
                    select 
                            x.name, 
                            x.adate, 
                            floor(max(x.timeshift)/3)::integer as absent_marks
                    from (
                             select 
                                    a.name,
                                    a.date as adate,
                                    b.date as bdate,
                                    dense_rank() over (partition by a.name, a.date order by b.date) as timeshift
                            from attendance a
                            left join attendance b 
                            on a."name" = b."name" 
                            and a.date <= b.date
                            and a.status = b.status 
                            where a.status = 'absent'
                    ) x 
                    where x.timeshift - 1 = datediff('day', x.adate, x.bdate)
                    group by x.name, x.adate
            ) sub1
            left join (                
                    select 
                            x.name, 
                            x.adate, 
                            floor(max(x.timeshift)/3)::integer as absent_marks
                    from (
                             select 
                                    a.name,
                                    a.date as adate,
                                    b.date as bdate,
                                    dense_rank() over (partition by a.name, a.date order by b.date) as timeshift
                            from attendance a
                            left join attendance b 
                            on a."name" = b."name" 
                            and a.date <= b.date
                            and a.status = b.status 
                            where a.status = 'absent'
                    ) x 
                    where x.timeshift - 1 = datediff('day', x.adate, x.bdate)
                    group by x.name, x.adate) sub2
            on sub1.adate = sub2.adate + 1
            and sub1.name = sub2.name 
            where (sub2.absent_marks = 0 or sub2.absent_marks is null)
            and sub1.absent_marks != 0
            ) z
    group by
            z.name
```

Comment: It did not give me the output. And instead of datediff() we have date_part in PostgreSQL. @peach